# np.where() with strings and multiple conditions to create a new column in Excel (python)

Tags: python, numpy

When trying to do a comparison with `np.where()`, I get the

```
Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

So I am trying to create a new column `"CUSTOMER STATUS"` in Excel that says either `"INACTIVE"` or `"ACTIVE"` based on values `"X"` in some other columns and thought that `np.where` would work.

```
file["CUSTOMER STATUS"] = np.where(file["Posting block for company code"] == "X" |
                                        file["Deletion flag for company code"] == "X", "INACTIVE", "ACTIVE")
```

is `np.where()` correct one to use here?

Thanks

Comment: Try with conditions in bracket; `np.where((file["Posting block for company code"] == "X") |
                                        (file["Deletion flag for company code"] == "X"), "INACTIVE", "ACTIVE")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the Precedence of Python Operators.

Use brackets around the conditions:

```py
file["CUSTOMER STATUS"] = np.where(
    (file["Posting block for company code"] == "X") |
    (file["Deletion flag for company code"] == "X"), 
    "INACTIVE", 
    "ACTIVE"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is:

```
file["CUSTOMER STATUS"] = np.where(
    np.logical_or(file["Posting block for company code"] == "X",
                  np.isin(file["Deletion flag for company code"], 
                          ["X", "INACTIVE", "ACTIVE"]))
```